# What is the regex of a CSS selector

Tags: css, regex

I'd like to parse a CSS file and add another CSS selector before every CSS selector.

From:

```
p{margin:0 0 10px;}
.lead{margin-bottom:20px;font-size:21px;font-weight:200;line-height:30px;}
```

I'd like:

```
.mySelector p{margin:0 0 10px;}
.mySelector .lead{margin-bottom:20px;font-size:21px;font-weight:200;line-height:30px;}
```

But my CSS file is really complex (in fact it is the bootstrap CSS file), so the regex should match all CSS selectors.

For now, I have this regex:

```
([^\r\n,{};]+)(,|{)
```

And you can see the result here http://regexr.com?328ps, but as you can see, there are a lot of matches that shouldn't match.

For example:

```
text-shadow:0 -1px 0 rgba(0,
```

matches positive but it shouldn't

Does someone have a solution?

Comment: You could use [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com) to do this job.

Comment: Um, CSS selector syntax is [quite complicated](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html). You might want to simplify your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So finally I've found a way better way to do it.

I use a LESS editor (eg: http://lesstester.com/)

and simply nest my whole css file:
.mySelector{ your css here }

Comment: Though this does not answer the question but it is very helpful. Thanks. Anyone can use less, by using just two tags.

Answer (score 36):

There isn't one. CSS selectors are not an example of a "[Regular Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)" and so cannot be parsed by a Regular Expression. You will need to build your own parser based on the CSS grammar specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#detailed-grammar

CSS is described as an LL(1) grammar, so you're probably better off using a tool like Yacc to generate your parser for you.

Comment: +1 It's very rare to see a correct answer on this kind of question.

Comment: @ascii-lime I paid attention during the Languages and Grammar courses in school - but I've completely forgotten how to work with LALR now :(

Comment: The fact that a language isn't regular doesn't always mean you can't parse it with a regular expression.  The reason is that modern regular expression implementations have more advanced features now that allow you to dive into slightly more complex language.  For example, balanced matching... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx

Comment: While the answer is technically correct (upvote!), the OP probably didn't necessarily want a parser that would handle every nuance of the CSS specification (which, as you say, is not a regular language).  It is possible to write a regular expression (or two) to handle 99% of real-world CSS to accomplish the OP's needs (as evidenced below).

Comment: This is a great answer to different question. The OP doesn't want a CSS parser. He/she just wants to perform a find-and-replace on CSS selectors within a text (CSS) file. There's no need to over think things.

Comment: @OliverMoran While the OP just wants to prefix each selector, that's actually a really hard problem and not necessarily straightforward: CSS has quoted strings, for example (URIs, `content:`, etc) which could coincidentally contain a valid CSS rule. You could naively split a rule's selectors on the comma character, but a comma can appear inside an attribute selector as a quoted value. It's also easy for a naive approach to get messed-up by `@media` and `@keyframes` rules, for example which add another layer of nesting in CSS... and so on...

Comment: @SteveWortham Agreed; however, most regexp implementations don't support nesting like that. Also, that doesn't give you a clear way to extract the selectors, only a way to test them. However, the question doesn't look like it's looking for a strict match, just enough to prefix every selector, and you likely won't need a full LL(1) parser for that.

Answer (score 28):

So I've finally found a REGEX that works for my requirements

```
([^\r\n,{}]+)(,(?=[^}]*{)|\s*{)
```

The key point was to add a **Positive lookahead** to avoid bad matches

```
(?=[^}]*{)
```

You can see the result here: http://regexr.com?328s7

The only precaution that I can recommend is to remove every block comment:

- bad sample with block comment: http://regexr.com?328sd

Comment: This also has a problem of media-queries and `@supports` directives.
I used this solution in [scope-css](https://github.com/dfcreative/scope-css) package.

Comment: It matches `@keyframes` also, which is not a selector

Answer (score 3):

A simple and readable regex is below:

`[\#\.\w\-\,\s\n\r\t:]+(?=\s*\{)`

you can test it on css code in this [tool](http://regexpal.com/)`

Answer (score 3):

It's true that you can not select css **selectors** using regex, but you can select css **rules** using regex, so you can make the job done in the inverse way:

1. format css file in order to no have selectors and rules in the same line.
   your code should look like this:

   > p{
   >       margin:0 0 10px;
   >   }
   >   .lead{
   >       margin-bottom:20px;
   >       font-size:21px;
   >       font-weight:200;
   >       line-height:30px;
   >   }
2. select all rules (regex : (^(.)*;)

   > p{
   >       **margin:0 0 10px;**
   >   }
   >   .lead{
   >       **margin-bottom:20px;
   >
   >       font-size:21px;
   >
   >       font-weight:200;
   >
   >       line-height:30px;**
   >    }
3. add some prefix to rules (example ####)

   > p{
   >       **####margin:0 0 10px;**
   >   }
   >   .lead{
   >       **####margin-bottom:20px;
   >
   >       ####font-size:21px;
   >
   >       ####font-weight:200;
   >
   >       ####line-height:30px;**
   >    }
4. select all lines not beginning with ####,not a return to line, and not a } (regex : ^[^#### \n }])

   > **p{**
   >           ####margin:0 0 10px;
   >       }
   >       **.lead{**
   >           ####margin-bottom:20px;
   >           ####font-size:21px;
   >           ####font-weight:200;
   >           ####line-height:30px;
   >        }
5. add your css prefix

   > **.my_class_prefix** p{
   >           ####margin:0 0 10px;
   >       }
   >       **.my_class_prefix** .lead{
   >           ####margin-bottom:20px;
   >           ####font-size:21px;
   >           ####font-weight:200;
   >           ####line-height:30px;
   >        }
6. delete the added prefix ####

   > **.my_class_prefix** p{
   >           margin:0 0 10px;
   >       }
   >       **.my_class_prefix** .lead{
   >           margin-bottom:20px;
   >           font-size:21px;
   >           font-weight:200;
   >           line-height:30px;
   >        }

Comment: Instead of "rule" I think you mean "property". The CSS spec defines a Style Rule as a combination of Selectors **and** Properties. But the regex you've posted is easily to break: it will fail to ignore a semicolon inside a quoted string.

Comment: @dai You are right, Given regex are just examples to explain my idea.

Answer (score 1):

Faced a similar problem and used the following to extract only CSS selectors and directives without comments and media queries:

`/^(?!.*@media)[\t ]*([a-zA-Z#.:*\[][^{\/]*\s*){[\s\S]*?}/`

Example: https://regex101.com/r/JmjthP/5

I'm sure it's missing some edge-cases but seems to be working for me.

See this question: [Ruby RegExp - Match all CSS selectors and directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504728/ruby-regexp-match-all-css-selectors-and-directives)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

`(?<=\s)[^ ]*\s*\{[^\}]+\:[^\}]+\}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I used for a similar problem. I wanted to remove all css rules that started with `@`. For this I used the following regex:

`@\s*.*\s*\{((?!\n\})[\s\S])+\n\}`

It makes the assumption that the rule ends on a new line. That way it can sort of handle nested css rules.

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't possible to write a single regular expression that matches any valid CSS selector, you can combine a couple regular expressions and a bit of logic to accomplish your goal.

The following uses Node's `fs` module to read the CSS, but you could get the raw CSS string however you want.

```
const fs = require('fs'),
    myClassName = 'mySelector',
    mySelector = '.' + myClassName,
    mySelectorRegex = new RegExp(`\\.${myClassName}([ .#[:(]|$)`),
    cssSelectorRegex = /[@.#a-zA-Z][^}]*?(?={)/g;

let css = fs.readFileSync('path/to/file.css').toString();

css = css.replace(cssSelectorRegex, match => {

    // Match is a string of selectors like '.foo' or '.foo, #bar'
    // We need to split it on the comma and handle each selector individually
    return match.split(',').map(selector => {

        selector = selector.trim();

        // Don't alter media queries, imports, or selectors that already contain '.mySelector'
        if (selector.startsWith('@') || selector.match(mySelectorRegex)) {

            return selector;

        }

        // Prepend '.mySelector ' to the selector
        return mySelector + ' ' + selector;

    // Combine the list of selectors back together
    }).join(',');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting discussion - not pure reg exp but a really short JS function:

```js
function cssNester(css, nestWith) {
  let kframes = [];
  css = css.replace(/@(-moz-|-webkit-|-ms-)*keyframes\s(.*?){([0-9%a-zA-Z,\s.]*{(.*?)})*[\s\n]*}/g, x => kframes.push(x) && '__keyframes__');
  css = css.replace(/([^\r\n,{}]+)(,(?=[^}]*{)|\s*{)/g, x => x.trim()[0] === '@' ? x : x.replace(/(\s*)/, '$1' + nestWith + ' '));
  return '/*' + nestWith + '*/\n' + css.replace(/__keyframes__/g, x => kframes.shift());
}
```