# Ruby RegExp - Match all CSS selectors and directives

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to match all the CSS selectors and directives below excluding any comments and any media queries.

```
a {color: red !important;}

#p1 {
        margin-top: 20px !important
      }

/* Client-specific styles */

      .ExternalClass,  
      .ExternalClass p,  
      .ExternalClass span,  
      .ExternalClass font,  
      .ExternalClass td,  
      .ExternalClass div {
        line-height: 100%;
      }

a {}

@media query {
    a { display:none }  
}
```

I've come up with the following RegEx: `[a-zA-Z#.:*]{1}[^\/*]+?{[\s\S]*?}`. This matches everything correctly but includes the `@media query`. I've tried using a negative lookahead e.g. `(?!.+@media.+)` but that didn't help.

What can I do to extract only the selectors/directives?

Example: https://regex101.com/r/JmjthP/3

**Solution**

With help from @Wiktor Stribiżew the working solution was this:

`/^(?!.*@media)[\t ]*([a-zA-Z#.:*\[][^{\/]*\s*){[\s\S]*?}/`

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/JmjthP/4

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made a few tweaks and it's working great. Do you want to post that as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Ok, posted with an explantion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!.*@media) *[a-zA-Z#.:*][^{]*{[\s\S]*?}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JmjthP/6)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*@media)` - no `@media` allowed after any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `*` - 0+ spaces
- `[a-zA-Z#.:*]` - a letter, `#`, `.`, `:` or `*`
- `[^{]*` - zero or more chars other than `{`
- `{` - a `{` char
- `[\s\S]*?` - 0+ chars, as few as possible.
- `}`  - a `}` char