# regular expression for finding CSS rules from css file

Tags: javascript

How do I get CSSRules from a stylesheet using regular expressions? I have tried but my expression doesn't work on rules that accecpt selectors like media queries or keyframes etc...
This is my expression
/([^}]*{)([^}])*[^{]*}/

...It works fine when finding CSS style rules.... But a keyframe or media rule won't work well... You can try it using match like so ->

```
const regex = new RegExp(/([^}]*{)([^}])*[^{]*}/, 'g'); 
var arr = document.head.querySelector('style').innerText.match(regex); // style tag that has enough CSS rules... including media queries
console.log(arr);
```

To summarize to purpose of the expression I'd say.... I am trying to get the result of 'document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].cssText'

here is an example

```js
//
const regex = new RegExp(/([^}][^;][^{]*{)([^}])*[^{]*}/, 'g');
const arr = document.querySelector('.wb-monitor').innerText.match(regex);
const screen = document.querySelector('#screen');
//console.log(arr)
if(arr !== null){
    arr.forEach(item => {
        if(item.trim().length > 0){
            screen.innerHTML += `<pre>${item}</pre>`;
        }
    });
} else {
   screen.innerHTML = '<span>No Match Found!</span>';
}
```

```css
        container {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            background: #ddd;
            height: 100%;
        }

        pre {
            border-left: 3px solid blue;
            background: rgb(93 88 88 / 60%);
            padding: 8px; 
        }

        .wb-monitor {
            width: 0%;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: monospace;
            margin-right: 2px;
            background: grey;
        }

        #screen {
            background: black;
            color: white;
            flex-grow: 1;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
<!-- Dummy css -->
        <div class="wb-monitor">
            .header-basic-light {
                padding: 20px 40px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
                height: 80px;
                background-color: #fff;
            }
            
            .header-basic-light .header-limiter {
                max-width: 1200px;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            
            .header-basic-light .header-limiter h1 {
                float: left;
                font: normal 28px Cookie, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                line-height: 40px;
                margin: 0;
            }
            
           
            
            @media all and (max-width: 600px) {
                @ keyframes me {
                    0% {
                        marin: 0;
                    }
                    100% {
                        margin: 100;
                    }
                }
            }

            @media all and (max-width: 600px) {
                .header-basic-light {
                    padding: 20px 0;
                    height: 85px;
                }
                .header-basic-light .header-limiter h1 {
                    float: none;
                    margin: -8px 0 10px;
                    text-align: center;
                    font-size: 24px;
                    line-height: 1;
                }
                
                .header-basic-light .header-limiter nav {
                    line-height: 1;
                    float: none;
                }
                .header-basic-light .header-limiter nav a {
                    font-size: 13px;
                }
            }
           
        </div>
        <div id="screen"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This might be an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/855027). What are you trying to do and what result are you expecting?

Comment: Using that RegExp with media queries produces the exact same result for style declarations that are not media queries. Please produce a [example] using [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the REGEX of a CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575845/what-is-the-regex-of-a-css-selector)

Comment: I updated my question with a runnable code.... I am trying to get all cssRules, by that I mean styleRules media rules, keyframesrules etc from any stylesheet... and as I said, the expression i formed works well in getting the style rules... as you'd see if you run the code.... but the expression stops as soon as it hits a closing brace  which is not efficient for media queries and keyframes and any other rules like them....

Comment: consider using a css library like: https://github.com/csstree/csstree

Comment: thanks but it doesn't help at all....i just checked it out..

Comment: Is there a specific reason why the CSS is inside a `<div>` instead of a `<style>` tag? The latter would allow you to loop over each style rule and read the selector, properties and values. Even in Media Queries and Keyframes.

Comment: It's in the div tag to show that I copied the contents of a CSS file.... I know there's an easy way... ie. document.stylesheets..... but it doesn't output the exact content of your stylesheet.. the comments, the way you defined the CSS properties..

Comment: Given that you know you can get the rules from `document.styleSheets` what is the reason you need to get them from a regex instead?

Comment: I am working on a project that involves updating stylesheet dynamically.... More like a CSS editor like that of the 'style panel' in chrome dev tools... I can't use document.stylesheets because the output isn't the same with the content of my stylesheet